# Qt / C++ - variable lose his value

Tags: c++, qt

I'm porting big application from Free Pascal to C++ (QT Creator). I'm very newbie in C++, this is my first meet with C++ (and C). I've been porting it for a few months. I had a lot of problems which I solved so I thought that I learned something from that day and C++ does not surprise me any more, but at the end (9 0% ported) I'm stuck. Lets start. I have this class:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    enum PageType {
        pt1,
        pt2,
        pt3,
        pt4
    };
    PageType mPage;
}
```

At runtime, `mPage` is changed. Seems that it is working fine (while debugging I see correct value), but in some case, when I get signal, I have condition `if (mPage==pt3)` it should be true but is not, debugger shows me that it has value 4042322160 (4042322160). I thought that I have some memory leaks or something. So I run valgrid, indeed I had few memory leaks and invalid read/write, but after fixing it, I still have same problem. Is anyone can tell me what I'm missing in C++ world?

Regards

Comment: You probably need to post a little more code than that. I suspect your object is being deleted.

Comment: You could also try initializing mPage in the constructor and seeing if that solves the problem. That would at least tell you that it's never set to `pt3` as you expect.

Comment: I could post more code but it is hard to debug where is a problem, I can't post all code because it is commercial product. And answering to your question, MyWidget is not deleted on 100% (this widget is never deleted in runtime, but in some case its mPage property lose value)

Comment: @Taylor. I'm initializing it in constructor, I have many stages when I point to this vairable and it has correct value, but in some case it has some magic 4042322160. Sorry that I can't post more code, I'm entrust for your tips which point me to where I made a mistake

Comment: Is it the child of another QObject? If so it may be getting automatically deleted when its parent is deleted.

Comment: No, MyWidget is widget which always exists (placed on main window) and it has `PageType mPage` variable in private section, so mPage should be alive until MyWidget is destroyed, but in some case mPage has strange value while MyWidget still working

Comment: And note that mPage is used only by its parent object, so by MyWidget

Comment: Have you setting a watchpoint on mPage, to see when it changes? Look at the "watch" command in GDB.

Comment: Is your value incorrect in a particular slot? You mentioned a signal, so I'm guessing there might be an issue with your signal-slot connection. If you can post the slot and connection syntax you're using, we might be able to correct that.

Comment: Check that you're not redeclaring mPage as a local variable in one of the functions. C++ allows multiple variables with the same name and will reference the one with the smallest scope.

Comment: Found problem. My fault. I have also array:
QColor mRowColors[1];

But in code I did:
mRowColors[0] = p.color(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Base);
mRowColors[1] = QColor(240,240,240);

Free Pascal in such case throw Access Violation